# How to hide internal system in our task killer in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in our thesis, its all about the *BATTERY DOCTOR SAVER* what my problem is, the .api list, what i want is to get only the application that is running not the internal system because in my thesis it also show the internal system. Is there a way how to remove that internal system in our task killer? so far this is my code for getting the running application :

```
    public void loadRunningProcesses() {

            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appinfolist = activityManager
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();

            Log.d(TAG, "AppInfoList Size: " + appinfolist.size());

            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
                TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
                runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
                runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
                adapter.addTask(runningtask);
runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName.substring(11));
            runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);

            }
        }

        class TaskObject {
            int pid;
            String processName;
            private boolean toKill;

            public int getPid() {
                return pid;
            }

            public void setPid(int pid) {
                this.pid = pid;
            }

            public String getProcessName() {
                return processName;
            }

            public void setProcessName(String processName) {
                this.processName = processName;
            }

            public boolean isToKill() {
                return toKill;
            }

            public void setToKill(boolean toKill) {
                this.toKill = toKill;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Polo Ravales](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9552178/2):

---

I already found a solution for this problem. I only use a substring and also make the first letter an uppercase for formality, look at my code :

```
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
        TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
        String ringgo = new String();

        ringgo = runningAppProcessInfo.processName.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (!ringgo.equals("system")){
            if (ringgo.length()>12){
            runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
            runningtask.setProcessName(ringgo.substring(12).substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ringgo.substring(13));
            adapter.addTask(runningtask);}
            else{
                runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
                runningtask.setProcessName(ringgo.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ringgo.substring(1));
                adapter.addTask(runningtask);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: casperOne: I flagged a post and was about to leave a comment on it, but you had deleted the post already in like 5 seconds! Amazing, keep up the good work - you're always on top of things it seems. Sorry to post OT comments but wanted to show my appreciation, feel free to delete.

Comment: @Madmartigan NP, given all that's going on, I'm going to let the comment stew for a while and bask in it.  Thanks for the support =)